# How to correctly convert C++ ulong 4 bytes IP address to C# type?

Tags: c#, c++, networking

From C++ client I'm sending a buffer of 6 bytes to C# server.

```
ULONG addr = htonl(server->sin_addr.s_addr);
USHORT port = server->sin_port; -> Already reversed to network bytes.

char frame[sizeof(USHORT) + sizeof(ULONG)];

memcpy(frame, &port, sizeof(USHORT));
memcpy(&frame[2], &addr, sizeof(ULONG));


int result = send(s, (const char*)frame, sizeof(frame), 0);
```

As you can see, the buffer contains: **[2 bytes port, 4 bytes address]**

---

On C# server side, Im then converting port and address from network to host bytes. I've checked to make sure and the received buffer is always 6 bytes.

```
ushort port = BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, 0);

byte[] temp = new byte[4];
Array.Copy(buffer, 2, temp, 0, temp.Length);

uint address = BitConverter.ToUInt32(temp, 0);
long addressx = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(address);

destPort = (ushort)IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder((short)port);
destAddress = (new IPAddress(addressx).ToString());
```

Sometimes, I'm getting an exception when initializing `new IPAddress(address)`, **ArgumentOutOfRangeException**.

What I don't understand is why it only happens sometimes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you use `htonl` and `NetworkToHostOrder` on the IP address (I known this is the portable way if you want to support both little- and big-endian nodes) and not the port?

Comment: Why is `addressx` defined as a `long` (64 bit?), when an IPv4 address is exactly 32 bit?

Comment: @Jonas I tried defining it as int and the issue is the same :/ I wrote that the port is already reversed.

Comment: A Uint32 is only 4 bytes and you want 6 bytes.

Comment: @jdweng No, can you see the buffer of address is 4 bytes?

Comment: You are helping too much.  Use the IPAddress(byte[]) constructor instead, byte order is already assumed to be in network order and the size of the byte[] ensures you'll always get an IPv4 address.

Comment: @HansPassant I have tried that and the conversion isn't correct for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your `addressx` is either less than zero or is greater than 0x00000000FFFFFFFF.

This is happening because you are calling `IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(address);` when `address` is a `uint`. Since there is no overload of `NetworkToHostOrder()` that accepts `uint`, this is promoting the argument to `long` and calling `NetworkToHostOrder(long)`. This is resulting in a negative value for some inputs.

What you need to do is to call the version that takes an int by using the `int` form of the address:

```
int address = BitConverter.ToInt32(temp, 0);
```

Now when you call `NetworkToHostOrder()` you will get a (possibly negative) `int` back, which you need to cast to `uint`:

```
uint addressx = (uint) IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(address);
```

Now this should work:

```
destAddress = (new IPAddress(addressx).ToString());
```

Comment: I've figured it out the moment you posted it! Thanks for your answer and explanation, makes much more sense now :)